# mysqldump: got errno 32 on write (1and1 shared host) as crontab

Tags: php, hosting, mysql

I'm using the exact code that 1and1 suggests for backing up MySQL DBs through mysqldump (http://faq.1and1.co.uk/archive/43.html)

```
$host= 'xxxx';
$user= 'xxxx';
$pass= 'xxxx';
$db=   'xxxx';

system(sprintf(
  'mysqldump --opt -h%s -u%s -p%s %s | gzip > %s/backup/' . time() . '.sql.gz',
  $host,
  $user,
  $pass,
  $db,
  getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT')
));
```

Have changed all permissions to 777 for purposes of testing. Still no luck. Continuing to get the error (errno 32 on write).

Any help is appreciated - this seems like a stupid fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this from a cron job, then `DOCUMENT_ROOT` won't exist. The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and other `$_SERVER` variables are effectively set up by the web server (see [the $_SERVER manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)), and if you're running the script directly from cron, there's no web server involved. See [this earlier, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100545/serverdocument-root-does-not-work-in-the-php-script-running-through-cron).

Try setting the path to your backup directory relative to the location of the PHP script. For example, if your script is in `.../your_folder/scripts/backup_script.php`, and your (pre-created) backup directory is `.../your_folder/backup/`, then

```
$backup_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../backup';
```

...and then use `$backup_dir` instead of `getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT')`.

It looks like your hosts's instructions are correct, but only if running the script from the web server, not from the command line.

Comment: This makes the error make more sense: errno 32 is "broken pipe", meaning that gzip exited before mysqldump finished output.  gzip falling over because it could not write to the output file sounds like a good culprit.

Comment: @Charles Indeed. In the case of DOCUMENT_ROOT being empty, gzip will be trying to write to `/backup/...`, which you'd very much hope a normal user wouldn't have permission to do :)