# CronJobs Permission Denied

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

Okay, so I made a cronjob to run every two minutes and set it up to send me an email. Well, this is the cronjob. /home/sites/psychowars.com/public_html/cronjobs/energy_minute.php
This is the email I receive.. nice:

> /home/sites/psychowars.com/public_html/cronjobs/energy_minute.php: Permission denied

Well, this is the PHP file that's suppose to run.

```
<?php
require '../stats/users_stats.php';
    {
    if ($energy < $max_energy) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET energy=(energy + 1) WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    }
?>
```

Every 2 minutes the user should recieve 1 energy if it's less than their max energy.
Any solutions on what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your cron line as part of your post - that way we can see what (exactly) you're executing. Sounds like a user/group/world permission issue and relative path.

Answer (score 0):

try to set $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] manually at the start of the script and don't use relative paths for cronjob scripts:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "/home/sites/psychowars.com/public_html";
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/stats/users_stats.php';
if ($energy < $max_energy) {
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET energy=(energy + 1) WHERE id='".$id."'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: What would I replace document_root with? Or would I keep it there?

Comment: If I actually load the page itself. the actual page with the PHP it will give the user the energy, but it seems like the cronjob isn't running it every 2 minutes I guess.

Comment: keep it, it is an predefined variable (but its empty when the script is run by cron)

Comment: if this won't help, check the file attributes of your script

Comment: Okay, well the PHP scripts work, because I can manually load them and will work properlly.. I think it's just the cron job not running them.

Answer (score 0):

You have answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100545/serverdocument-root-does-not-work-in-the-php-script-running-through-cron)

$_SERVER variable is not set from cron job.

Answer (score 0):

If is still not working you can outsource your cronjob with www.guardiano.pm and call an http post or get request to yoursite.com/users_stats.php so you don't need to care about cronjobs. If the only thing that you need is that IMHO you can avoid that