# cron job on wordpress site is generating fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I did created a cron job for a script in my wordpress site which is using a theme. When the script is called with cron it is not working fine. Some function which are in that script are not recognized, because script not see them and report them as undefined function.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_option()
```

Do i need to include something more, or how to make that script to run normally with cron job ?

Comment: did you include the wp stuff? did you include them with an absolute path? remember that cron jobs have a different working directory than scripts running under a webserver.

Comment: You should probably consider using [**wp_cron**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron), the psuedo cron function that works with Wordpress.

Comment: Is `get_option()` defined in the same file that the Cron Job is running? If not, then you are probably referring to the file that contains `get_option()` via the `$_SERVER` variable (e.g.: `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'path/to/file')`. However, [the `$_SERVER` variable is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100545/serverdocument-root-does-not-work-in-the-php-script-running-through-cron) whenever a page is loaded via a Cron Job.
You might want to try using `__file__` instead.

Comment: @Chris - get_option() is defined in functions.php if I remember correctly. It's a built in WP function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_cron()`, Wordpress's built in cron function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

Otherwise, the issue with `get_option` not being recognized is probably because Wordpress core is not loaded.  You need to require `wp-load.php` in your external php script with the absolute path to that file:

`require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");`