# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] not recognised by php unit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am writing a unit test for my code with phpunit. Code class has following:

```
<?

    // Dependencies
    //
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/configs.php");

class xyz{
..
...
..
}
?>
```

Test Class is as follows:

```
<?php

require_once("xyz.php");

class testxyz extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

    public function setUp(){
        $this->xyz= new xyz();
    }

    public function testEmail(){

        $this->xyz->SetEmail('abc');
        $name = $this->xyz->GetEmail();
        $this->assertEquals($name == 'abc');
    }


}
```

When i run php unit on my test class, I get following error:

```
Fatal Error: Class xyz not found
```

This error got resolved by giving `<?php instead of <?` at the top of my code class.

Secondly, I get following error after first error was resolved:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/includes/configs.php'.
```

Which means $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was not recognised by php unit.

Since code class can't be changed, how can I successfully run php unit without changing my code class. Please suggest any work around such that `<?` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` start working with php unit.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` relies on a specific environment. When you call PHPUnit it runs PHP without that environment.

Typically you want your code under test to be independent of the environment. A common setup is to have a bootstrapper that can bootstrap from a webserver-environment and a PHPUnit environment.

Rather that using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` you can set the base directory in your bootstrapper by using the magic constants: `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`.

Similar to `$_SERVER`: `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` are also not available in a PHPUnit environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can set $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] manually in your setUp method

```
public function setUp(){
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "...";
    $this->xyz= new xyz();
}
```

**Reason of $_SERVER is not set:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100577/1071156

Comment: I have a custom path $_SERVER['PATH_TO_REFERENCED_CODE'] and this is not working.

Comment: thank you .. I am setting it to $_SERVER['PWD'] in setup